# blender gpu render time isn't stable why?

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, rigging

im trying to render an animation in blender with cuda , currently im using gtx 750 ti for render , i have a scene with a simple character in it and no major change just a character walking , once i hit the render it took 1hr to render a single frame then i cancelled the render and closed all my background apps (antiviruses and fences ...) then in viewport hided anything so it takes less gpu memory , then i hit render and the exact same frame tooks 15mins instead of 1hr , now that i know memory affects my render time each frame takes 15 mins but question is when it continues rendering the problem goes back , render time increases  and after 10 - 12 renders i'll get system is out of gpu memory ! and i tested it out by closing the blender and reopening it again and by rendering the exact same 12th frame instead of 1hr render time it takes 15 mins again and render time rises up in each frame , it seems like blender is keeping those renders or some data from them to memory that causes a render time increase i also baked dynamic hair and softbody simulations cause i think they have nothing to do with gpu memory, now im asking if there is any option to help me to disable blender from holding weird data from previous renders that causing render speed drop , thanks .

render engine is also cycles

blender version is 3.15

Comment: This is a wild guess but that sounds like GPU clock rate change.  That can happen when your GPU's performance is throttled because it is becoming too hot.  You didn't mention your OS so I can't give you specifics, but you can check this with tools that monitor GPU temperature and clock rate.

Comment: @MartyFouts  very thanks didn't knew that , i kinda figured it out , i noticed that blender makes an autosave every 2 mins even in render i disabled that and also reduced video sequencer memory to zero , then i reduced tiling size to 512 , the render time became 17 mins persistence for each frame , but still got out of memory problem tho , i find out by disabling hair bvh that problem fixes too for me